# How to create onboarding ui with alertdialogs?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, uiviewanimation

I'm building an app I want it to have a very simple walk-through/on-boarding experience which shows some messages indicating the functionality of every item on screen. The messages must have a next button that shows the next message and close the former one.

something like this:

[image: Expected UI]
[image: Expected UI2]

I've been looking on many onboarding widgets but none of them allow me to present something like I described, So I figured I could make it by using AlertDialog on the app UI.

I want it to execute automatically as soon as the screen is loaded so I have this in the initstate:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_showOpenDialog);
  }

  _showOpenDialog(_) {
    showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return keyboardDialog(context);
        });
  }
```

this calls the widget I created for the custom message, which is basically returning an AlertDialog with texbutton within. this button should get me to the next alert dialog box and close the previous one, so I though this might work but it doesn´t do anything on pressed:

```
TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return keyboardDialog(
                              displayHeight, displayWidth, context);
                        })),
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                      },
```

I tried to put first the pop() instruction:

```
TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return keyboardDialog(
                              displayHeight, displayWidth, context);
                        })),
                      },
```

but what happens is that it close the alert dialog and the background layout and shows the next dialog message like this:

[image]

¿What can I do to achieve the desired transition?

-------           Update         ----------------------------

I changed the name of the context passed to the second AlertDialog, but the behavior is the same.

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_showOpenDialog);
  }

  _showOpenDialog(_) {
    showDialog(
        barrierDismissible: false,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          var displayHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
          var displayWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
          return micDialog(displayHeight, displayWidth, context);
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          //capa inferior, donde se muestran los botones
          Container(
            child: Container(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              //color: Colors.white,
              child: ButtonBar(
                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.settings_outlined,
                        color: Colors.black87,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {}),
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 0, 20),
                      child: micButton()),
                  IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.keyboard), onPressed: () {})
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          //capa superior donde se muestrean los mensajes
          Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: Center(
              child: Text("Hi!, Test APP"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget micButton() {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 70, height: 70),
      child: ElevatedButton(
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.white,
            shape: CircleBorder(),
          ),
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(
            CupertinoIcons.mic,
            color: Colors.black87,
            size: 40,
          )),
    );
  }

  Widget micDialog(displayHeight, displayWidth, context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: displayHeight * 0.63,
          width: 350,
          left: displayWidth * 0.01,
          child: AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            content: Text("Mic Description       ",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (keyboardContext) {
                          return keyboardDialog(
                              displayHeight, displayWidth, keyboardContext);
                        })),
                      },
                  child: Text("NEXT", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: displayHeight * 0.77,
          left: displayWidth * 0.375,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
            size: 90,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget keyboardDialog(displayHeight, displayWidth, keyboardContext) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: displayHeight * 0.63,
          width: 350,
          left: displayWidth * 0.15,
          child: AlertDialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            content: Text("Keyboard Description",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(keyboardContext).pop(),
                  child: Text("NEXT", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: displayHeight * 0.77,
          left: displayWidth * 0.68,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_drop_down,
            size: 90,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had the complete code I could try to show you a working example but, nonetheless I think the problem lies as to which context you are passing to the navigator.
Let me explain :

```dart
TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                          return keyboardDialog(
                              displayHeight, displayWidth, context);
                        })),
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                      },
```

Here you are pushing your dialog and inmediately popping it, hence no changes as you stated.

Now in the second case the context that gets popped is the one previous pageroute insted of the dialog as intended.

My advice check carefully which context you are passing to the navigator, be aware of calling every new BuildContext as `context` as you could shadow other variables, try using context, then keyboardDialogContext and so on.

The context is a snapshot of the widget at a given position in the tree , and if you are passing a position higher than where the first dialog is created the first PageRoute it encounters is the one of the widget that appears in the background.

---

EDIT

---

```
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                        showDialog(
                            barrierDismissible: false,
                            context: context,
                            builder: (keyboardContext) {
                              return keyboardDialog(displayHeight, displayWidth, keyboardContext);
                            })
                      },
```

So I was able to reproduce the issue and thought it was a little strange and after giving it some thought I realized it was the intended behavior.

The problem lied in that you were using the navigator to push a new route

```
                     Navigator.push(context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (keyboardContext) {
                          return keyboardDialog(
                              displayHeight, displayWidth, keyboardContext);
                        })),
```

So the screen got black because a complete new page was pushed so if for example you turned the background of the keyboardDialog to red then:
[image]

You could see that an emty page was created with the dialog.

Instead you needed to `showDialog` this method creates an Overlay that sits on top of the precedent Route which was your intended purpose.

Comment: hi croxx5f, If I try to do what you suggested, but maybe I didn't implemented correctly. I posted the whole code, so if you can take a look I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hi @juanjoseperezhernandez I was wrong with my first advice.I updated my answer. But take my inital advice into account because although this was not the case I have  had problems because it in the past.

Comment: I see, so I should use showDialog with every AlertDialog that I need... I'm going to try and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: using showDialog instead of navigator push worked as I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is something like this, [tutorial_coach_mark](https://pub.dev/packages/tutorial_coach_mark), it's a walkthrough rather than onboarding:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tutorial_coach_mark/tutorial_coach_mark.dart';

List<TargetFocus> targets = List();

 @override
 void initState() {
    targets.add(
        TargetFocus(
            identify: "Target 1",
            keyTarget: keyButton,
            contents: [
              TargetContent(
                  align: ContentAlign.bottom,
                  child: Container(
                    child:Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Titulo lorem ipsum",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 20.0
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pulvinar tortor eget maximus iaculis.",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white
                            ),),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
              )
            ]
        )
    );

    targets.add(
        TargetFocus(
            identify: "Target 2",
            keyTarget: keyButton4,
            contents: [
              TargetContent(
                  align: ContentAlign.left,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Multiples content",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 20.0
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pulvinar tortor eget maximus iaculis.",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white
                            ),),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
              ),
              TargetContent(
                  align: ContentAlign.top,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Multiples content",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 20.0
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pulvinar tortor eget maximus iaculis.",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white
                            ),),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
              )
            ]
        )
    );

    targets.add(
        TargetFocus(
            identify: "Target 3",
            keyTarget: keyButton5,
            contents: [
              TargetContent(
                  align: ContentAlign.right,
                  child: Container(
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "Title lorem ipsum",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.white,
                              fontSize: 20.0
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin pulvinar tortor eget maximus iaculis.",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white
                            ),),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
              )
            ]
        )
    );
}

void showTutorial() {
    TutorialCoachMark(
      context,
      targets: targets, // List<TargetFocus>
      colorShadow: Colors.red, // DEFAULT Colors.black
       // alignSkip: Alignment.bottomRight,
       // textSkip: "SKIP",
       // paddingFocus: 10,
       // opacityShadow: 0.8,
      onClickTarget: (target){
        print(target);
      },
      onClickOverlay: (target){
        print(target);
      },
      onSkip: (){
        print("skip");
      },
      onFinish: (){
        print("finish");
      },
    )..show();
  }
```

Comment: This seems interesting, I'm going to take a look into it.